# How to say when I have motion sickness in a car?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

I wonder if I could say something like:

> "I feel nauseous."

or

> "I got carsick."

when I feel sick and going to vomit due to a motion in a car. Does the sentences above sound natural?

Comment: *Motion sickness* is not a count noun, so it is ungrammatical to talk about having "a" motion sickness as you did in the title.

Comment: @tchrist Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both sound natural but are referring to different points in time in your unfortunate situation.

"I feel nauseous" is present tense (i.e. right *now* you feel sick), the better of the two choices for saying you might vomit soon.

"I got carsick" is past tense (i.e. at some point you became sick) and will most likely be what you say after you have already vomited.

As Weather Vane in the comments pointed out, You can also throw in the immediate future tense by saying "I am going to be sick," which is the best option for informing people that things are not going well for you and are about to be worse.

Comment: "I am going to be sick" is about the *immediate* future and is the right answer to the question: it's going to happen next. For the future of the journey in general you can say "I will be sick".

Comment: Minor additional information: purists will say you should say *I feel* ***nauseated***, not *nauseous*. That something nauseous is something that produces nausea rather than something affected by nausea.  However, that's ceased to actually be the case in idiomatic use, and, because of this,  *nauseous* has taken on the other meaning, too, in modern use.